# SqlDataReader causes the webpage not to load

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am using a database to relate a Department's Name with it's unique mailing code i.e. Accounting has mailing code 1337. ShortName and ID are the fields of the database that are being queried.

The Schema is

- `ID int`
- `ShortName nvarchar(255)`

This is done on the backend of a webpage using C#. I have used a `SqlDataReader` object elsewhere in the same code but no error was caused by this. I think I have a syntax error somewhere or I am trying to stick a string into an int or something silly but I can't see it.

The `SqlConnection` is set up correctly as it is used for a query upon page load and works when the indicated line is commented out.

```
SqlDataReader SQl_Reader;
string cmdString = "SELECT ShortName FROM departments WHERE (ID = " +
  department_Text.SelectedValue.ToString() + ")"; //a selected value in department_text would be the mailing code such as 1337, or 1304.

SqlCommand SQl_Command2 = new SqlCommand(cmdString, SQl_Connection);

SQl_Reader = SQl_Command.ExecuteReader();

string deptName = SQl_Reader["ShortName"].ToString();//This should assign the deptName = the value in SQl_Reader but it causes the page not to load. Not sure what is wrong with it

SQl_Reader.Close();
SQl_Connection.Close();
```

I have tried this multiple different ways even using a proprietary Connection, Command, and Reader just for this query. I have used a `SqlDataReader` for a similar purpose with the same two fields in another function of the code and it works perfectly. Any insights would be very appreciated.

Comment: You have a pretty serious sql injection vulnerability in this code. You need to be using parameterized queries instead. Most likely the value of `department_Text` is not what you think it is, and the query is not returning any results, therefore throwing an exception when you call `ToString()` on a null reference.

Comment: shouldn't you call SQL_Reader.Read() before reading anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to use a reader, you need to call `Read()` before getting the values.

If you get want a single value, then you're better off using `ExecuteScalar()` instead.

Also use a parameterized query to protect against SQL injection (and other benefits too)..

```
    SqlDataReader SQl_Reader;
    string cmdString = "SELECT ShortName FROM departments WHERE ID = @ID;"
    SqlCommand SQl_Command2 = new SqlCommand(cmdString, SQl_Connection);
    SQl_Command2.Parameters.Add("@ID", department_Text.SelectedValue);
    SQl_Reader = SQl_Command.ExecuteReader();
    SQl_Reader.Read();
    string deptName = SQl_Reader["ShortName"].ToString();

    SQl_Reader.Close();
    SQl_Connection.Close();
```

or better..

```
    SqlDataReader SQl_Reader;
    string cmdString = "SELECT ShortName FROM departments WHERE ID = @ID;"
    SqlCommand SQl_Command2 = new SqlCommand(cmdString, SQl_Connection);
    SQl_Command2.Parameters.Add("@ID", department_Text.SelectedValue);
    SQl_Reader = SQl_Command.ExecuteReader();
    SQl_Reader.Read();
    string deptName = SQl_Command.ExecuteScalar() as String;

    SQl_Reader.Close();
    SQl_Connection.Close();
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to .Read() from the SQl_Reader before it will have any data.
normally you would do

```
While (SQl_Reader.Read() )
{
   // Get values here
}
```

If you're certain there will only be one row returned, then you should change your query to

```
Select top 1 ShortName FROM
```

But you still need the Read(). Also I agree with the comment about being open to an injection attacks. you need to pass department_Text.SelectedValue in as a query parameter

Answer (score 1):

I've assumed that ID is primary key, so no other possible values for specyfic ID, then [`ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) will do the job.

```
string cmdString = "SELECT ShortName FROM departments WHERE (ID = @depId)";

using (SqlCommand SQl_Command2 = new SqlCommand(cmdString, SQl_Connection))
{
    //a selected value in department_text would be the mailing code such as 1337, or 1304.
    SQl_Command2.Parameters.Add("@depId", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = department_Text.SelectedValue;

    string deptName = (string)SQl_Command2.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

Don't forget to use [`SqlCommand.Parameters Property`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) instead of string concatenation.

I'ts good to use [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to automatically dispose objects, more about it: [Is SqlCommand.Dispose() required if associated SqlConnection will be disposed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808036/is-sqlcommand-dispose-required-if-associated-sqlconnection-will-be-disposed).