# F# append to list in a loop functiuonally

Tags: list, f#

I am looking to convert this code to use F# list instead of the C# list implementation.

I am connecting to a database and running a query usually with C#  would create a list of a type and keep adding the list while the datareader has values. How would I go about converting this to use an F# list

```
    let queryDatabase (connection: NpgsqlConnection) (queryString: string) =
        let transactions = new List<string>()
        let command = new NpgsqlCommand(queryString, connection)
        let dataReader = command.ExecuteReader()

        while dataReader.Read() do
           let json = dataReader.GetString(1)
           transactions.Add(json)
        transactions
```

Comment: See  [:: (cons)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233224.aspx) operator. Also note that C# List<> is a wrapper around an array, whereas F# list is a pure linked-list. F# list is very fast to add elements, but uses more memory

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tricky thing here is that the input data source is inherently imperative (you have to call `Read` which mutates the internal state). So, you're crossing from imperative to a functional world - and so you cannot avoid all mutation.

I would probably write the code using a list comprehension, which keeps a similar familiar structure, but removes explicit mutation:

```
let queryDatabase (connection: NpgsqlConnection) (queryString: string) =
  [ let command = new NpgsqlCommand(queryString, connection)
    let dataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
    while dataReader.Read() do
      yield dataReader.GetString(1) ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Tomas' answer is a solution to use in product code. But for sake of learning F# and functional programming I present my snippet with [tail recursion](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fsharpteam/archive/2011/07/08/tail-calls-in-fsharp.aspx) and cons operator:

```
let drToList (dr:DataReader) =
    let rec toList acc =
        if not dr.Read then acc
        else toList <| dr.GetString(1) :: acc
    toList []
```

This **tail** recursion function is compiled into imperative-like code, thus no stack overflow and fast execution.

Also I advice you look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808036/is-sqlcommand-dispose-required-if-associated-sqlconnection-will-be-disposed) C# thread  and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233240.aspx) F# documentation to see how properly dispose your command. Basically, you need to use smth like this:

```
let queryDb (conn: NpgsqlConnection) (qStr: string) =
   use cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(qStr, conn)
   cmd.ExecuteReader() |> drToList
```

And if we go deeper, you should also think about exception handling.

Comment: Please note, your results would be in reverse order.