# Sql to CheckBox || checkbox situation on button if/else (C#)

Tags: c#

Thank You guys!!! really!!
checkbox situation on button if/else (solved)

but how can i transfer a sql situation e.x True/false to checkbox.
Or if there is another way to do this:
When i open a winform i want to keep in memory what was my checkbox condition.

Comment: Checkbox in a winform ? WPF ? MVC view  ? Webform ?

Comment: Assuming that the id column is unique, then you need to use `ExecuteScalar`

Comment: Please find your solution in the revision history and post it as an answer of its own, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [`ExecuteScalar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) method like this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select rent_panel from parameters where id= '1'", con);

con.Open();

bool rent_panel = (bool)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

if (rent_panel == true) 
{
    //..
}
else
{
    //..
}
```

Please note that based on your question, I am assuming that the `rent_panel` column is of type `bit` (it can be either true or false).

I am assuming also that the id column has unique values (it is the primary key, right?)

Side note: you should always dispose your connection and command objects using the `using` keyword. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1808056/2290059).

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Your Data Source");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select rent_panel from parameters where id= '1'", con);
con.Open();
bool rent_panel = (bool)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
if (rent_panel)  //(rent_panel == true) 
{
//..
}
else
{
    //..
}
con.close();
```