# MySql exception while doing several requests after one another

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a aspnetcore webservice which does several requests after one another. I get an exception at different times. the Error message is:

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: error connecting: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.
>
> at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()
>
> at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
>
> at bdtFood.Controllers.FoodController.Get(Int32 id, Int32 idMeeting)
>
> at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
>
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__28.MoveNext()

How can i pervent this exception. There shouldn't be more than one request at the same time.

EDIT: code for a request.

```
while (cn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
        {

        }
        cn.Close();
        cn.Open();
        Modells.Room room = new Modells.Room(-2, "dummy");
        MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM room WHERE idRoom = @idRoom", cn);
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("@idRoom", MySqlDbType.Int32, 11).Value = idRoom;
        using (reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                room = new Modells.Room(reader.GetInt32(0), reader[1].ToString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you disposing your connections and commands?

Comment: I for every request I use a new connection and a new command. Could this be the problem? I thought this would not be the problem because I use them one at a time.

Comment: It is impossible to give you any other more specific advice without seeing some of your code.

Comment: I changed my code to using the same connection within a controller. and the same error still occurs

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `using` around all Commands and Controllers.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1808056/34092 for more details.