# Disposing SqlCommand

Tags: c#, ado.net, idisposable, sqlconnection, sqlcommand

Because `SqlCommand` implements `IDisposable`, I would normally approach an ADO query as follows.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
{
    // Execute command, etc. here
}
```

However, what if I need to execute multiple commands during a single connection? Do I really need a new `using` block for each command?

The examples I found from Microsoft don't use a `using` block for `SqlCommand`s (or even call `Dispose()`). What are best practices regarding disposing `SqlCommand`?

Comment: There is no reason not to reuse a single SqlCommand if you don't need overlapped access.

Comment: I personally use a new using block for every command object inside the connection block.  You can always just reset your command information and clear the parameters and run a new query with the existing command object, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, best practice is to dispose them.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
   connection.Open();

   using (SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand(query1, connection))
   {
      // Execute command, etc. here
   }

   using (SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand(query2, connection))
   {
      // Execute command, etc. here
   }

   using (SqlCommand command3 = new SqlCommand(query3, connection))
   {
      // Execute command, etc. here
   }
}
```

MSDN probably doesn't show it because it's [not really needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808036/is-sqlcommand-dispose-required-if-associated-sqlconnection-will-be-disposed) in case of `SqlCommand`. But in my opinion it's bad from microsoft to not use this pattern on every object that implements `IDdisosable` because people aren't getting used to it.

Comment: Ok, I can see that being best practice in the sense that it is the most thorough. But I wonder how many people are actually doing this if Microsoft examples don't?

Comment: @JonathanWood: i have already edited my answer mentioning exactly this

Answer (score 2):

The using statement ensures that `Dispose` is called even if an exception occurs while you are calling methods on the object. You can achieve the same result by putting the object inside a try block and then calling `Dispose` in a `finally` block.

In this case you use `using` for each command block:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
   using (SqlCommand cmd1= new SqlCommand(query1, connection))
   {
   }

   using (SqlCommand cmd2= new SqlCommand(query2, connection))
   {
   }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No you do not. There are 2 ways that your multiple commands could be bundled within one connection and command.

The first would be to just reuse the existing CMD object, but changing the CommandText and other CMD.properties as needed.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {

    con.Open();

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query1, con)) {
        // cmd.CommandType = CommandType.xxxxx
        // add any parameters
        // Execute()

        cmd.CommandText = query2;
        // reset CommandType if needed
        // adjust parameters if needed
        // Execute()

        cmd.CommandText = query 3;
        // reset CommandType if needed
        // adjust parameters if needed
        // Execute()
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

The second method would be to create a *Stored Procedure* on the database server and call that in the one CMD object

```
-- Database
CREATE PROCEDURE schema.sproc_CommandBatch (
    -- any variables here
) AS
BEGIN
    -- query 1

    -- query 2

    -- query 3
END
GO


// C#
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {

    con.Open();

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("schema.sproc_CommandBatch", con)) {
        // cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        // add any parameters
        // Execute()
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is that if it implements IDisposable then Dispose() it. <s>In fact the examples [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) do all call Dispose. With a wrinkle:</s>

The first example, where it opens a SqlDataReader, calls .Close() on the command in the finally clause. In fact, .Close is just a wrapper around .Dispose() (and no longer appears in the documentation). *Jonathan Wood in his comment pointed out that the Close is on the reader. This is wrong.*

For multiple calls on the same connection you can:

1. Re-use the one command (declared in one using). I don't like this
   myself, but that's just me: I find it...ugly.
2. Use multiple commands in multiple usings. That's what I'd do.

'Best Practice' is a bit amorphous. There's never unanimous agreement that what person A touts as Best Practice is better than what person B is recommending, let alone C, D or E. Use your own judgement.

Comment: The first example calls close on the reader, not the connection. I'm not saying they don't exist, but I've yet to view an example from Microsoft where `Dispose()` is called on a `SqlCommand`.

Comment: @JonathanWood - excellent point, and apologies for missing that.