# Closing SqlConnection in a ASP.NET and memory issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

In the ASP.NET app I'm working with the data layer that has functions such as:

```
public DataSet GetFacilitiesInfo(string userName = null)
{
    DataSet Ds = new DataSet();
    string storedProcName = "FacilitySelect";

    SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection();
    SqlCommand sqlCommand;
            
    try
    {
        DBConnection cn = new DBConnection();
        sqlConn = cn.DBConnTIP(_connectionString);
        sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(storedProcName, sqlConn);
        sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;               

        SqlDataAdapter sqlDA = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);
        sqlDA.Fill(Ds);

        return Ds;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
    finally
    {
        sqlConn.Close();
        sqlConn.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Per Microsoft

> The Dispose method is primarily implemented to release unmanaged resources.

I know in the above code we can use the `using { ... }` but behind the scenes, CIL translates it to exactly the same function calls.

My understanding is that `SqlConnection` (ADO.NET) is a managed object, so why do we dispose of it?

*The suggested duplicate question has nothing to do with my question at all.*

To improve this post I suggest putting the following as duplicate, at least it has some similarity:

[Is SqlCommand.Dispose() required if associated SqlConnection will be disposed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808036/is-sqlcommand-dispose-required-if-associated-sqlconnection-will-be-disposed)

Comment: the SqlConnetion itself may have unmanaged resources like a tcp socket...

Comment: You may want to re-read your "is a managed object, so why do we dispose of it" - non-managed resources don't have a concept of ".Net interface/metod/class" so it is quite unclear where do *you* think `Dispose` should be implemented...

Comment: @ Daniel A. White    So by this logic, we should dispose of any  .NET Managed object (that implements IDisposable) because behind the scenes it may have references to unmanaged objects.

Comment: @SNash Exactly. Anything that implements `IDisposable` should either: **1)** be wrapped in a `using` block, **2)** be wrapped in try/finally blocks, or **3)** Be used as a member of a type that itself implements `IDisposable`. **Always**.

Comment: I think that the way the connection pool works needs the connections to be disposed, otherwise the pool can easily be exhausted before the process runs out of memory.

Comment: Honestly, this question has been around since invention of .NET. Why ask again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My understanding is that SqlConnection (ADO.NET) is a managed object, so why do we dispose of it?

The "managed" word here *only refers to **memory**.* So the memory used for the `Sqlconnection` object is managed and will be released appropriately, but the network, file, special shared memory, or named pipe resources used for completing the connection are *not managed*, and need to be disposed properly.

In fact, *anything* that implements `IDisposable` should either:

1. Be wrapped in a `using` block
2. Be wrapped in `try`/`finally` blocks
3. Be used as a member of a type that itself implements `IDisposable`.

**Always**

*(And the corollary is `IDisposable` should only be used when there's an unmanaged resource of some kind involved.)*

---

As for the `finally` block, in this case, yes, the `finally` block is enough, and `using` is not strictly required.

However, the `catch` block here does absolutely nothing useful... worse, it destroys the call stack for any eventual exception. In other words, it's not only safe to just remove the `catch` block, but you're *actively better off* if you do.

Once that's done you can save even more code by also completely replacing both the `try` and `finally` blocks with a `using` block, and from there we can save another two lines, as well as a level of indentation, with the new `using var` construct.

Lastly, the `sqlConn` variable is over-written before ever using the `new SqlConnection` object allocated when it's first declared — the object is completely wasted. So we can clean that up, too.

Put it all together like this:

```
public DataSet GetFacilitiesInfo(string userName = null)
{
    DataSet Ds = new DataSet();
    DBConnection cn = new DBConnection();

    using var sqlConn = cn.DBConnTIP(_connectionString);
    using var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("FacilitySelect", sqlConn);
    using var sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);
        
    sqlDA.Fill(Ds);            
    return Ds;
}
```

This is safer (all the IDisposables are accounted for), has better error handling (call stack is preserved), uses noticeably less code (always a win), and with absolutely no loss of function.

For completeness, here's a version that also takes a few guesses to make use of the `userName` argument:

```
public DataSet GetFacilitiesInfo(string userName = null)
{
    DataSet Ds = new DataSet();
    DBConnection cn = new DBConnection();

    using var sqlConn = cn.DBConnTIP(_connectionString);
    using var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("FacilitySelect", sqlConn);
    using var sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);
    
    sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;  
    // I have to guess the type and length
    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.NVarchar, 25).Value = userName;
    if (userName == null) sqlCommand.Parameters["@UserName"].Value = DBNull.Value;
        
    sqlDA.Fill(Ds);            
    return Ds;
}
```

That said, it is somewhat common to want actual meaningful error handling in this type of method, with a real `catch` block. And once you do that, you're back to where a `finally` block is just as good.

Comment: "In fact, *anything* that implements IDisposable ...". Well [*mostly*](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/10792496-what-harmless-is-that-all-it-s-got-to-say-harmless) anything. [MemoryStream.Close() or MemoryStream.Dispose()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274590/memorystream-close-or-memorystream-dispose) - answer: neither is needed (but it doesn't hurt).

Comment: @AndrewMorton It's the same kind of point as "if you have to ask how much it costs..." :)

Comment: Lol :) At least if someone in the future tries to argue it from the **Always**, there will be my little comment with the reference to the exception. I do realise it was done for consistency with the other streamy-things.

Comment: "IDisposable should only be used when there's an unmanaged resource of some kind involved" Yep.  But unfortunately Component implements IDisposable, which gives it to many types that otherwise don't need it, like SqlCommand. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.component?view=net-7.0

Comment: @David Browne  So, If I have a managed type that implements IDisposable,  How I can know behind the scenes if it uses an unmanaged type? if there is no way for this then we have to dispose of every applicable manage type.

Comment: Generally yes, dispose all the disposables.  Alternatively, you could examine the implementation, and determine that changing it in the future would be a needless and horrendous breaking change, and just not dispose.  This is the case, for instance, for SqlCommand, which is rarely disposed in practice.

Comment: is disposing of SqlCommand harmless?

Comment: @SNash As long as you really are done with it, yes.